# Covariance and indicator function relations

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, covariance, mixing

Let $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ be  two (sub) sigma-algebras of some probability space. If $A\in\mathcal A$ and $B\in\mathcal B$, why the following equality holds:
$$Cov(1_A-1_{A^c},1_B)=E((P(B\lvert \mathcal A)-P(B))(1_A-1_{A^c}))?$$
where the function $1_W$ stands for the indicator function given a measurable set $W$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Cov}(1_A-1_{A^c},1_B)&=\mathsf{E}[(1_B-\mathsf{E}1_B)(1_A-1_{A^c})] \\
&=\mathsf{E}\!\left[\mathsf{E}[(1_B-\mathsf{E}1_B)(1_A-1_{A^c})\mid \mathcal{A}]\right] \\
&=\mathsf{E}\!\left[\mathsf{E}[(1_B-\mathsf{E}1_B)\mid \mathcal{A}](1_A-1_{A^c})\right] \\
&=\mathsf{E}\!\left[(\mathsf{E}[1_B\mid \mathcal{A}]-\mathsf{E}1_B)(1_A-1_{A^c})\right].
\end{align}

Comment: Did you use $E(1_A-1_{A^c})=0$ in the first equality?

Comment: No. 
$$\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=\mathsf{E}[(X-\mathsf{E}X)(Y-\mathsf{E}Y)]=\mathsf{E}[(X-\mathsf{E}X)Y].$$